# Why aren't we seeing 9th Doctor after he regenerated into the 10th?

Tags: doctor-who

We see past Doctors frequently in *Doctor Who*. The 10th Doctor has shown himself lots of times after being relived of his duties. Excluding *The Day of The Doctor*, we've also seen the 5th Doctor (Peter Davison), the 8th Doctor (Paul McGann) and the 11th Doctor (Matt Smith) after they were out of service.

Why doesn't the 9th Doctor (Christopher Eccleston) show up? I am asking from out-of-universe perspective of course.

Comment: Because Moffat and the BBC are bastard dalek scum.

Comment: We can only speculate as to *why*, but Eccleston has refused to return to the role at least once - he refused to return for the War Doctor episode, and I believe he was invited a time or two for other shows.  He has turned them down without public comment.

Comment: Supposedly there were problems with Eccleston getting along with the higher ups on the show that kept him from signing on for more than one season. This is according to Bad Wild while attending an acting Master Class held at the Theatre Royal in Haymarket.

The article is here: http://www.denofgeek.us/tv/doctor-who/20897/christopher-eccleston-is-this-why-he-really-quit-doctor-who

The transcript of the podcast is found here: http://badwilf.co.uk/eccleston-explains-why-he-left-doctor-who

Comment: Just as a trivia note, Eccleston is the *only* Doctor (aside from Matt Smith) who hasn't reprised the role after regenerating

Comment: @JasonBaker Technically, Matt Smith showed up after his regeneration, when he called Clara in the first Capaldi episode. Granted, the regeneration was in that episode, so it probably doesn't count as a "reprisal," but in the show's timeline(?) it took place after. Also, any relation to Tom or Colin?

Comment: Wait, is op asking about the actor returning or clips of existing material being used?

Comment: @cde Talking about the actor's return..

Comment: @Jason Baker - John Hurt hasn't either.

Comment: There is a parallel here with Tom Baker's declining to reprise the role of the 4th doctor in the 25th anniversary special.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For *Day of the Doctor* specifically, Eccleston was asked to return and ultimately decided to decline. In an interview with *SFX* magazine, quoted by [GiantFreakinRobot.com](http://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/scifi/stephen-moffat-eccleston-didnt-return-doctor-whos-50th.html), Moffat said:

> ’I had an initial contact with Chris and, in a very amiable and gentlemanly way, he didn’t feel that he could come back to it,’ he says. Moffat continues, ‘There wasn’t any big fuss about it — I had a couple of meetings with him, and he was perfectly pleasant, and indeed quite enthused about the show, but he just doesn’t do that, it’s just not him.'

In general, it's hard to say. Eccleston did *not* leave the show on good terms, according to the [*Bad Wilf* podcast](http://badwilf.co.uk/eccleston-explains-why-he-left-doctor-who):

> “I left Doctor Who because I could not get along with the senior people. I left because of politics. I did not see eye-to-eye with them. I didn’t agree with the way things were being run. I didn’t like the culture that had grown up around the series. So I left, I felt, over a principle."

Eccleston's been very tight-lipped about his departure in general, so it's hard to say which "senior people" he's talking about, but bad blood is as likely a factor as anything else.

Moffat's comment in my first quote seems to indicate that Eccleston doesn't like to go go back to projects once he's moved on from them, which is another plausible explanation.

That possibility is given credence by Eccleston himself, who, when asked if he'd be returning for *Day of the Doctor*, [reportedly said](http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/tvandradioblog/2011/jul/21/doctor-who-christopher-eccleston):

> "No, never bathe in the same river twice."

[Omegacron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80384/why-arent-we-seeing-9th-doctor-after-he-regenerated-into-the-10th/80386#comment171093_80386) raises an interesting point in comments: why not just CGI Eccleston's face into the show, since the BBC owns the rights to the Ninth Doctor's appearance?

For one thing, they sort of did. The last scene of *Day of the Doctor*, pictured below, features the likenesses of all previous Doctors including both John Hurt and Christopher Eccleston:

[image: The Twelve Doctors]

And of course he appeared in archive footage during the big "All the Doctors fly in to save Gallifrey" scene.

Moffat commented on this in *Doctor Who Magazine*, as well as the decision to not show John Hurt regenerating into Eccleston, as [BBC America reports](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2014/05/why-doctor-who-didnt-christopher-eccleston/):

> “It was one thing to include [him] among all the other archive Doctors, as they flew in to save the day,” he explained, “in fact, it would have been disgraceful to have left anyone out – but placing him in that [regeneration] scene might have given the impression he’d actually turned up for filming, which would have been crossing the line.”
>
> He added: “not taking part in the 50th was a difficult decision for Chris, taken after a lot of thought and with great courtesy, and not respecting his wishes would have been grossly unprofessional and disrespectful to a good man and a great Doctor.

Comment: The rumour is that he had some strong views about the character and show. He wanted them to do some plotlines with a deep political bias and when the showrunners refused his ideas, outright, he left in a very big huff.

Comment: For the record, refusing to show up for the specials (whatever his personal enmity with the showrunners) makes him a git.

Comment: Apparently Eccleston doesn't buy into the idea that you *can't* step (or, by extension, bathe) in the same river twice.

Comment: I've read that he didn't like how the events of Day Rendered Nines pain pointless.

Comment: It's too bad. I liked him.

Comment: Also, it'd be awesome if they used him as War Doctor..

Comment: Originally the War Doctor was going to be the Ninth Doctor. When Eccleston declined to appear, Moffat came up with a new, secret (until then) Doctor.

Comment: @Richard - if that's the case, I'm glad it went down the way it did. As a viewer, I'm already hit over the head with political bias everywhere I go. I definitely don't wanna see it in my entertainment. That rumor does sound in character for Eccleston, though - he's very big into the artsy, 'make a statement' theory of acting.

Comment: @Richard - Where did you hear that story? The Bad Wilf transcript linked above makes it sound more like he didn't approve of the way one or more of the directors was treating the crew: *"You know, it’s easy to find a job when you’ve got no morals, you’ve got nothing to be compromised, you can go, ‘Yeah, yeah. That doesn’t matter. That director can bully that prop man and I won’t say anything about it’. But then when that director comes to you and says ‘I think you should play it like this’ you’ve surely got to go ‘How can I respect you, when you behave like that?’"*

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Believe it or not, it came from a guy in a bar. The guy actually worked as an FX specialist on the season 1 Dr Who reboot so it's not quite as bad as it sounds.

Comment: @Hypnosifl If you wanted to, you could read that as a self-righteous "git" complaining about people who want to make entertainment without turning everything into some sort of "statement," and using bullying a prop man as a hypothetical or hyperbole. Of course, that doesn't mean that it *is* a rant by a self-righteous git, but you could read it that way.

Comment: @Richard - Interesting, thanks--could be a combo of both I suppose, either way it sounds like he thought he was standing up for egalitarian principles of some kind, self-righteously or no. Too bad he won't come back to the show but he still does say positive things about it in public, like [this](http://www.digitalspy.com/british-tv/s7/doctor-who/news/a509735/christopher-eccleston-on-bfi-doctor-who-event-i-love-the-doctor.html)...also a lot of posters on Gallifrey Base say he's always gracious with fans he runs into, someone posted [this example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtV1TgcexKE).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Refusing to even cameo in the season specials makes him a gimboid in my opinion. Half a day of filming is hardly an imposition and it would mean a lot to his loyal fans.

Comment: @Richard - Well, the "Year of the Doctor" special edition of *Doctor Who Magazine* indicates on p. 18 that Eccleston did seriously consider coming back for the anniversary, and had a number of friendly talks with Moffat about it, but decided against being part of it. It also says that even before contacting Eccleston, Moffat "had doubts that it was the Ninth Doctor who had fought in the Time War." Personally I was glad we got John Hurt as an incarnation, and I think it makes more sense story-wise that Nine was newly-regenerated in "Rose".

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I'm guessing their negotiations were civil but conducted via agents and never went anywhere.

Comment: @Richard - "Never went anywhere" may be true but *Doctor Who Magazine* does say they talked in person: 'Steven had a couple of enjoyable meetings with Christopher to discuss his involvement and the direction of the story. In *The Guardian*, Steven explained that the pair had enjoyed a "very amiable and gentlemanly" conversation and that the actor considered the project "quite seriously" before turning it down. "It's just not the sort of thing he does," explained Steven. "But Chris was perfectly sweet and kind about it."'

Comment: That's ok - nowadays we just replace the actor with a CGI version. Even if they don't have rights to Eccleston's face, they DO have rights to the 9th Doctor character and HIS appearance. Hey-O!

Comment: Based on your first comment above, @Omegacron, I'm guessing you're not a big fan of the 13th Doctor's 2 series. Neither am I.

Comment: @FreeMan - nope, not a big fan. At first I didn't like the idea of them making The Doctor a woman, but the idea grew on me since Time Lords changing gender was already established in the canon. Whittaker herself does an okay job but I was kinda meh about her portrayal of the character. The writing is what killed it for me, though - totally downhill when compared to previous versions. When you're introducing already controversial changes to a franchise, the writing has to be high quality if you want to win over fans, and IMHO they fell completely flat in that regard.

Comment: Well stated, @Omegacron. Lines like "OK fam" just kill it for me.